# Get rid of [Vue warn] in production mode error of mutating v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have set `Vue.config.productionTip = false` as its default to `false`. But when changing a `v-model` I receive the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "name" found in the [path-to-the-.vue-file]

I have also checked the vue config file:

```
Ebrahims-MacBook-Pro:~ ebrahim$ vue config
Resolved path: /Users/ebrahim/.vuerc
{
 "useTaobaoRegistry": false
}
```

It has only `useTaobaoRegistry` option.

Even typing a character throws errors [Vue warn], how can I get rid of it?

Comment: the problem is somewhere else, it's not the configuration try to provide more code please

Comment: Well, here is my code: in the template, I have something like this: `<template><div>{{name}} <input v-model="name"/></div></template>`

Comment: please provide the whole code and components hierarchy

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Thanks, Here is the code https://codesandbox.io/s/jvwr083305

Comment: try to add .sync modifier like `<HelloWorld
      name.sync=`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, does not work you can see yourself on the codesandbox