# vuejs typescript and child components "Avoid mutating a prop directly"

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm going round in circles here.

I have a vuejs2 app up and running with typescript but hitting an error when i try to pass data to a child component that originates from the store.

```
<template>
    <div>
       <form-error :error422.sync="errors"></form-error>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import FormError from '@/components/FormError422.vue';
  import cloneObj from '@/utils/cloneObj';

  @Component({
    components: {
      FormError,
    },
  })
  export default class RegisterForm extends Vue {
    get errors() {
      return cloneObj(AuthenticationModule.errorRegister);
    }
</script>
```

The child

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{error422.errors}}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { Generic422 } from '@/ms-authentication'

@Component
export default class FormError422 extends Vue {
  @Prop() private error422: Generic422 = {
    errors: [],
  };
}
</script>
```

But whatever i do it throws a warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "error422"
```

Comment: try to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786353/get-rid-of-vue-warn-in-production-mode-error-of-mutating-v-model/55791206#55791206)

Comment: doesnt really enlighten typescript decorators though. but thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're trying to set `error422` **default value** as:

```
errors: [],
```

And you're setting it up directly in the `FormError422` class, via the `=` assignment.

This is not the way you should be using the `@Prop()` decorator to set up a default value. Instead, you are **directly mutating the prop** instead of setting up the default value.

therefore, Vue warns you because you should not do that.

To set up a prop default value with the `@Prop` decorator, do this:

```
@Prop({default: {errors: []}}) private error422!: Generic422;
```

Comment: Ahh i see! Quite new to decorators, they keep tripping me up. Thanks for the help, works perfectly.